# How to change the ownership logs of cron fiels

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, cron, cron-task

How can I change the ownership logs of cron tasks when they are creating by crontab?

At the moment all the files that are created is owned by `root` I need this to changed to for example `steve`.

Any help please

Answer (score 0):

Each user have it own crontab.

In order to change the ownership of steve crontab logs you have to

```
sudo su steve

crontab /path_to_cron_file

crontab -e
```

Here is steve crontab and from now on any log is created it will be owned by steve.

Now you have to sudo su root and change the crontab to an other cron file or set the default

```
sudo su root
crontab /etc/crontab
```